# RxBluetooth unable to establish connection with device

Tags: android, bluetooth, rx-java2, rxbluetooth

I would like to use [RxBluetooth](https://github.com/IvBaranov/RxBluetooth) to transfer some text between two Android devices.
I'm able to scan and see nearby devices, though while trying to connect to one of them I face the following failure:

---

*D/BluetoothUtils:* isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null

*W/BluetoothAdapter:* getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback

*D/BluetoothSocket:* connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[65]}

**java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1**

---

This is the code I run in order to establish a connection with a selected `BluetoothDevice`:

```
mRxBluetooth.observeConnectDevice(bluetoothDevice, UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
            .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<BluetoothSocket>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket) throws Exception {
                    // Unable to reach here.
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    // I reach this point with the message:
                    // java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
                }
            })
```

Bluetooth is enabled on both devices, as I'm able to discover one from the other.

Permissions I use are:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/Bluetooth/RxEcho) transfers text between two devices using RxBluetooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.
I forgot to `observeBluetoothSocket()`:

```
        mRxBluetooth
            .observeBluetoothSocket("MyConnection", UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
            .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
            .subscribe(this::observeIncomingMessages,
                    throwable -> {/*Handle error*/});
```

[Commonsguy](https://github.com/commonsguy)'s [RxEcho](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/Bluetooth/RxEcho) ( the suggested sample app in *CommonsWare*'s comment ) helped me realize this fact.
[RxEcho](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/Bluetooth/RxEcho) also helped me discover [RxJava2 Extras](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava2-extras) by [David Moten](https://github.com/davidmoten) which made reading data from the socket very convenient:

```
        Strings.from(btSocket.getInputStream())
           .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
           .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
           .subscribe(data -> {/* Post data to LiveData*/},
                   throwable -> {/* Handle error*/});
```

Thank you for taking the time and reading my question.